# Optional-chaining in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, package.json, optional-chaining

I'm using optional chaining on an object which in turn gives this error after compiling the code

For example

```js
const someObj = {pet_animals: {'dog', 'cat'}};
const duplicate = someObj?.wild_animals;
```

tsconfig file

[image]

Error message

[image]

Comment: `{pet_animals: {'dog', 'cat'}}` is not valid code. I suspect the error comes from it, rather than the optional chaining.

Comment: Also `someObj?.wild_animals;` would likely fail to compile in TS as there is no `wild_animals` property on the object.

Comment: just so that it doesn't fail we're using optional-chaining right?

Comment: TBH, I don't see how it would fail - the object is definitely defined on the first line, so using optional chaining on the second line only protects if the object is `null` or `undefined`...which is never going to be the case.

Comment: well, the error message is not in regards whether wild_animals exists or not.. i'm not able to use optinal chaining in the working project while if i create new temporary project and use same data it works fine without any compilation error

Comment: Again: `{pet_animals: {'dog', 'cat'}}` is not valid code.

Answer (score 1):

optional chaining was introduced in ES2020 [freeCodecamp.org](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-optional-chaining/#:%7E:text=Optional%20chaining%20was%20introduced%20in,in%20the%20final%20ECMAScript%20standard.). If you are your using js version before ES2020, you will get that error.

That might be the reason why you couldn't use optional chaining,

solution:

```
duplicate = someObj.wild_animals ? someObj.wild_animals : undefined
```